# Как разобрать matrix на scale, rotate, translate, skew?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation, transform

Дело такое, `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("transform")` возвращает `matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty)`. C `translate` всё вроде бы просто: `translateX = tx`, `translateY = ty`. А вот как вытащить scale, rotate, skew я немного не понимаю потому как во первых в rotate и scale должны быть градусы, во вторых:
вроде как `skewX = b`, `skewY = c`, а `scaleX = a`, `scaleY = d`, но при этом что бы повернуть элемент в матрице `a = cos(x)`, `b = sin(x)`, `c = -sin(x)`, `d cos(x)`.
Вообщем из набора параметров matrix я бы ещё составил а вот из matrix вытащить параметры вообще не понимаю как. Подскажите пожалуйста как перевести матрицу в понятный простому человеку язык или подскажите как можно получить свойство `transform` не в `matrix`, а в `scale`, `rotate`, `translate`, `skew`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В [черновике спецификации](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#MatrixDefined) описано какие значения, что означают.

Трансформации осуществляются с помощью матрицы трансформаций, в общем случае (3D) матрица 4х4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Матрица, которую вы получаете `matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty)` представляется в следующем виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы правильно отметили:  `tx, ty` - отвечают за перемещение.

За масштабирование отвечают значения лежащий на главной диагонали, в нашем случае это `a,d`, при это `a` - масштабирование по ширине, `d` - по высоте.

`c,b` - отвечают за наклон

и все вместе `a,b,c,d` - за поворот.

Подробнее можно увидеть на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие преобразования называются Афинными, подробнее о них можно узнать:

[Wikipedia: Афинные преобразования](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)
[Аффинное преобразование и его матричное представление](http://compgraphics.info/2D/affine_transform.php)

Comment: Разобрался с scale, rotate и translate. Но skew не пойму как skew вытащить ?

Comment: @Kirpich643, на самом деле, если применено сразу несколько преобразований, то определить их весьма нетривиально, так как преобразования представляют из себя произведение матрицы на вектор или сложение матриц, и так как у нас имеется всего два состояния: начальное - фактически единичная матрица, и конечное - то весьма проблематично узнать вектора на которые мы умножали матрицу

Comment: В черновике спецификаций есть Decomposing a 2D matrix, из неё собственно и выходят scale, rotate и translate, но из неё выходят m11, m12, m21, m22 и я так понимаю это позиции в матрице, но я не понимаю зачем они и почему они не совпадают с входными ?

Comment: @Kirpich643, не не не, не совсем так: перечитайте еще раз ответ. Общий случай трансформаций - трехмерный, для него используется матрица 4х4, для двухмерных трансформаций, используется **та же** матрица 4х4, а которой стоят 0 в третьем столбце/строке везде кроме главной диагонали.

Comment: а выходят они потому, что при двухмерном преобразовании используются только две координаты, `x,y`