# Как рассчитать матрицу SVG-преобразования по значениям rotate / translate / scale?

Tags: svg, матрицы

У меня есть следующая последовательность трансформаций SVG:

```
<g transform="translate(20, 50) scale(1, 1) rotate(-30 10 25)">
```

Необходимо написать формулу matrix в соответствии с необходимыми трансформациями

```
<g transform="matrix(?,?,?,?,?,?)">
```

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне сделать это?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/15133977/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Translate(tx, ty) "перемещение" можно записать в виде матрицы:

```
  1  0  tx
  0  1  ty
  0  0  1
```

Scale(sx, sy) "увеличение" в виде матрицы:

```
  sx  0  0
  0  sy  0
  0   0  1
```

Rotate(a)  "вращение"

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)  0
sin(a)   cos(a)  0
0        0       1
```

Вращение `rotate(a, cx, cy)` в комбинации с перемещением  `translation(-cx, cy)`, с последующим перемещением назад в (cx, cy), достигается записью матрицы:

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)  -cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx
sin(a)   cos(a)  -cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy
0        0       1
```

Если вы просто умножите это на матрицу `translation`, вы получите:

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)  -cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx + tx
sin(a)   cos(a)  -cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy + ty
0        0       1
```

Что соответствует матрице SVG-преобразования записью в одну строку:

`(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a), -cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx + tx, -cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy + ty)`

В вашем случае это: матрица `(0,866, -0,5 0,5 0,866 8,84 58,35)`.

Если вы включите преобразование масштаба (sx, sy), матрица будет:

```
(sx × cos(a), sy × sin(a), -sx × sin(a), sy × cos(a), (-cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx) × sx + tx, (-cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy) × sy + ty)
```

Обратите внимание, что это предполагает, что вы делаете преобразования в том порядке, в котором вы их написали.

*Примечание переводчика:*

[Связанный ответ от](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/473015/28748) @Grundy

Я уверен что, чем больше разнообразных ответов с разной методикой изложения, тем лучше и будет легче разобраться в этом довольно сложном вопросе.

*Полезные ссылки для более углубленного изучения вопроса:*

[Затерянная документация или transform: matrix3d](https://habr.com/ru/post/166751/)

[Матрица преобразований](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/matritsa-preobrazovanii)

[Transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)

Comment: за стеной текста теряется то, что чтобы получить результат нужно просто перемножить матрицы отдельных трансформаций в оригинальной последовательности

Comment: @Stranger in the Q вы разве не заметили, что это перевод, а не авторский топик. Поэтому ваши советы по подаче материала, как мне видится, не корректны. Есть желание, пишите свой авторский ответ, прямо здесь, галочка свободна

Comment: Ну пусть это будет критика оригинала, может кому-то это поможет понять про важность очередности умножения

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `"В вашем случае это: матрица (0,866, -0,5 0,5 0,866 8,84 58,35)."`  Константин, читать надо внимательней,- ответ автора последовательно вел к конечной цели вопроса

Comment: я все еще раз перечитал. и я бы все равно не понял про перемножение и последовательность, если бы не знал о чем речь до прочтения.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ на мой взгляд всё логично и последовательность соблюдена как в вопросе - translate, scale, rotate/ В одном только месте дополнено, но это общеизвестный приём, что идет дополнительное translate для отката после масштабирования

Comment: еще заметил  -  в `rotate` содержатся градусы а в `sin` и `cos` необходимо передавать радианы

Comment: @Stranger in the Q интересно, как это ты заметил Прочитал другую [статью по ссылке, которую я добавил?](https://habr.com/ru/post/166751/) rotationYMatrix = $M([
[Math.cos( b), 0, Math.sin(b),0],
[0,1,0,0],
[Math.sin(-b), 0, Math.cos(b), 0],
[0,0,0,1]
])  Всё правильно у автора в ответе здесь написано. Sin(45) в формуле в градусах для наглядности, а реально записывают в атрибуты матрицы в радианах - p/4= 3.1415 /4 = 0.785

Comment: в ответе все правильно, об этом нет в тексте, однако это очень распространенная ошибка, сам частенько напарываюсь, особенно когда workflow не простой

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это не ошибка, а традиционная форма записи общей формулы матрицы, которая 100% присутствует во всех руководствах по матрицам. Так как при записи `sin(45)` всем понятно, что происходит поворот на 45 градусов, то если бы было в теории одни цифры радиан 0.785, то вообще было бы ничего не понятно :) для тех кто начинает изучать матрицы Могут добавить пояснения в авторский текст. Но с другой стороны компилятор svg не принял бы запись sin(45), а только радианы

Comment: в том то и проблема что 45 радиан это вполне корректный угол, просто много оборотов, я часто напарываюсь на это в геодезических задачах, где сложно понять, когда градусы а когда радианы получаешь на вход, особенно если получаешь по конвейеру

Answer (score 3):

В качестве примера использования `matrix` в SVG трансформациях привожу работы мастеров "old school"
Эти файлы на моем ПК находятся давно. Поэтому буду благодарен тому, кто укажет ссылку на первоисточник.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 -100 900 900' preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin meet'>
<defs>
<pattern id="motif" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 150 150" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<path id="bezi1_1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 76.24509811401367 75.74509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_2" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 73.75490188598633 74.25490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_3" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 75.74509811401367 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_4" transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 74.25490188598633 76.24509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_5" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 75.74509811401367 76.24509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_6" transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 74.25490188598633 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 76.24509811401367 74.25490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_8" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 73.75490188598633 75.74509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_9" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 223.75490188598633 74.25490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_10" transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 224.25490188598633 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_11" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 223.75490188598633 75.74509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi1_12" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 225.74509811401367 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C0,48 27.401962012052536,48.117648273706436 74.90196201205253,74.11764827370643" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 76.24509811401367 150.3627471923828)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_2" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 73.75490188598633 -0.3627471923828125)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_3" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 150.3627471923828 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_4" transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 -0.3627471923828125 76.24509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_5" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 150.3627471923828 76.24509811401367)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_6" transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 -0.3627471923828125 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 76.24509811401367 -0.3627471923828125)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_8" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 73.75490188598633 150.3627471923828)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_9" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 223.75490188598633 -0.3627471923828125)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_10" transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 149.6372528076172 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_11" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 223.75490188598633 150.3627471923828)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi2_12" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 300.3627471923828 73.75490188598633)" d="M 0 0 C15,-8 32.35294187068939,-15.5 42.35294187068939,0" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 75.24509873986244 150.36274734139442)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_2" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 74.75490126013756 -0.36274734139442444)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_3" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 150.36274734139442 74.75490126013756)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_4" transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 -0.36274734139442444 75.24509873986244)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_5" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 150.36274734139442 75.24509873986244)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_6" transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 -0.36274734139442444 74.75490126013756)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 75.24509873986244 -0.36274734139442444)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_8" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 74.75490126013756 150.36274734139442)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_9" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 224.75490126013756 -0.36274734139442444)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_10" transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 149.63725265860557 74.75490126013756)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_11" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 224.75490126013756 150.36274734139442)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="bezi3_12" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 300.3627473413944 74.75490126013756)" d="M 0 0 C34,-17 4.5,-27.539216309785843 0,-51.53921630978584" pointer-events="none" cursor="move" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
</pattern>
<g id="MyPath" transform="translate(-75 -75)" >
<g id="bezi1" place="1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 77.49019622802734 76.49019622802734)">
<path id="bezirect1" d="M 0 0 C0,96 54.80392402410507,96.23529654741287 149.80392402410507,148.23529654741287" pointer-events="visible" cursor="pointer" stroke="limegreen" fill="limegreen" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
</g>
<g id="bezi2" place="2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 77.49019622802734 225.72549438476562)">
<path id="bezirect2" d="M 0 0 C30,-16 64.70588374137878,-31 84.70588374137878,0" pointer-events="visible" cursor="pointer" stroke="green" fill="green" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
</g>
<g id="bezi3" place="3" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 75.49019747972488 225.72549468278885)">
<path id="bezirect3" d="M 0 0 C68,-34 9,-55.078432619571686 0,-103.07843261957168" pointer-events="visible" cursor="pointer" stroke="lime" fill="lime" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1"/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(150 150)">
<circle cx="75" cy="225" r="4" style="fill:red;stroke:red;fill-opacity:0.2"/>
<circle cx="75" cy="75" r="4" style="fill:red;stroke:red;fill-opacity:0.2"/>
<circle cx="225" cy="225" r="4" style="fill:red;stroke:red;fill-opacity:0.2"/>
<path d="M75 75 75 225 225 225z" style="fill:none;stroke:black;fill-opacity:0.2"/>
</g>
<g transform="translate(225 225)">
<use xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="1" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a1" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="3" values="0;180" begin="1"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a1.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a2" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0;90" begin="a1.end"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a2.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a3" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0;-90" begin="a2.end"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a3.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" fill="freeze" dur="3" values="1 1;-1 1" begin="a3.end" additive="sum"/>
<animateTransform id="a4" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="3" values="0;90" begin="a3.end" additive="sum"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a4.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a5" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0;90" begin="a4.end" additive="sum"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a5.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a6" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0;180" begin="a5.end" additive="sum"/>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)" visibility="hidden">
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a6.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a7" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0;-90" begin="a6.end" additive="sum"/>
</use>
<g visibility="hidden">
<use xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="scale(-1 -1)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="rotate(90)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="rotate(-90)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)"/>
<use transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a7.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a8" attributeName="transform" type="translate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0 0;0 300" begin="a7.end"/>
</g>
<g visibility="hidden">
<use xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="scale(-1 -1)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="rotate(90)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="rotate(-90)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)"/>
<use transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a8.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a9" attributeName="transform" type="translate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0 0;300 0" begin="a8.end"/>
</g>
<g visibility="hidden">
<use xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="scale(-1 -1)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="rotate(90)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="rotate(-90)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use xlink:href="#MyPath" transform="matrix(0 1 1 0 0 0)"/>
<use transform="matrix(0 -1 -1 0 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<use transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" xlink:href="#MyPath"/>
<set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" dur="0" begin="a9.end" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="a10" attributeName="transform" type="translate" fill="freeze" dur="2" values="0 0;300 300" begin="a9.end"/>
</g>
</g>
<g transform="translate(75 , 75)">
<rect x="-75" y="-175" width='100%' height='100%' fill='none' fill-opacity="0.5">
<set attributeName="fill" to="url(#motif)" begin="a10.end + 1" fill="freeze"/>
</rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Ещё примеры:**

[Example #1](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/bPWwdv)

[Example #2](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/rEmMOg)